# JsPDF Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to save a div as a PDF using jsPDF.
Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/waleedbinahmed/bfj6qktv/11/
and here is a fiddle that someone else has uploaded: https://jsfiddle.net/waleedbinahmed/8s4qvu27/

The second fiddle is working fine.

I have tried to mimic the second fiddle i.e. including the same js and Jquery libraries. But on my fiddle, I am getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined".

I don't know what I am missing on my fiddle that is causing the issue. Please help me out with what needs to be updated with respect to the second fiddle so that I can save a div a PDF.

JS library: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

  <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button onclick="javascript:createPdf()" id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function createPdf() {
     var doc = new jsPDF();
    
      source = $('#content')[0];
    
      specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
          return true
        }
      };
    
      doc.fromHTML(
        source,
        15,
        15, {
          'width': 170,
          'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        }
      );
      doc.save('sample-file.pdf')
    }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i did watch to your fiddle (the first one that was not working correctly), and just paste [js library from the correct fiddle](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js)

and its working. sounds like your imported library doesn't work. and also the working fiddle has a jquery 3.4.1 implemented